# correct sign when converting sin to cos (or vice versa) using sin = sqrt(1-cos^2)

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'm using the formula sin = sqrt(1-cos^2) to convert from cos to sin where source angle is not known an a call to arccos is too expensive. This operation obviously produces a wrong sign if source angle is in the 3rd or 4th quadrants. Could someone recommend me an effective way to compute the correct sign?

Thank you!

Comment: Is StackOverflow the right place for this question?

Comment: We're making the assumption he's doing some programmatic computation on this. :)

Comment: I believe yes, because it's about fast sin+cos implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The correct sign **will** depend on the quadrant of the original angle. If you don't have the angle, the solution is ambiguous.

Note that the arccos will not solve your problem because it will return only angles in the 1st and 2nd quadrants.

You simply do not have enough information!